# Go DynamoDB Expression Add can't add to list

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I want to add an int to a list in DynamoDB. This works:

`update := expression.Set(
        expression.Name("signers"),
        expression.Name("signers").ListAppend(expression.Value([]int{theInt})),
    )
expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithUpdate(update).Build()`

But only if there is a value already in the list. I want to create the list if it doesn't exist. I tried:

`.Add(
        expression.Name("signers"),
        expression.Value(theInt),`

and

`.Add(
        expression.Name("signers"),
        expression.Value([]int{theInt}),`

Which both return:

`ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type:LIST`

How do I set the type of theInt to a list?

I must be missing something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use Set to add a new list, and Add to add elements to an existing list?

Comment: Thanks Ian - how would I set up a condition to make that decision?